# how to use "this" inside mongoose userschema.methods in typescript

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, jwt, mongoose-schema

i am using mongoose with typescript and jsonwebtoken to create a login api. i am new to typescript. in the user.model, i cant access any schema property using the "this" method. for eg, user.methods gives me a compile error of "Property 'tokens' does not exist on type 'Document'.ts(2339)".

```
export interface IUser extends Document {
    name:string,
    email: string;
    password: string;
    tokens: {token: string}[],
    encryptPassword(password:string): Promise<string>;
    validatePassword(password:String): Promise<boolean>;
}
const userSchema  = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        trim: true
    },
    tokens: [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
})
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
    const user = this
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id.toString() }, "thisismysecretkey")
    user.tokens  = this.tokens.concat({token})
}
```

Here in the userSchema.generateAuthToken, i am getting Property 'tokens' does not exist on type 'Document'when i use user.tokens or this.tokens.. please tell me what i am doing wrong. Thsnks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try provide an explicit `this` parameter. For more info, see [this parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)

```
import { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser extends Document {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  tokens: { token: string }[];
  encryptPassword(password: string): Promise<string>;
  validatePassword(password: String): Promise<boolean>;
}
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    trim: true,
  },
  tokens: [
    {
      token: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
});
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function (this: IUser) {
  const user = this;
  const token = user._id.toString() + 'thisismysecretkey';
  user.tokens = this.tokens.concat({ token });
};
```

package versions:

```json
"mongoose": "^5.11.9",
"typescript": "^3.7.2"
```